# Why my component column do not highlight?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcomponent

[image: myFrame]

As you can see from the image I have my jtable in the frame with two column name and icon. The icon column doesn't highlight. Why? This is my renderer. My icon is a JComponent Object with a green rectangle

```
public class myRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) 
    {
        if (hasFocus)
            setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
        else
            setBorder(null);

        return (Component) value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of `TableCellRenderer`:

> **hasFocus** - if `true`, render cell appropriately. For example, put a special border on the cell, if the cell can be edited, render in the color used to indicate editing

probably the icon column is not editable and/or the cell does not have the focus.

(use debugger or `println` to see if `hasFocus` is true)

Answer (score 0):

> My icon is a JComponent Object with a green rectangle

A `TableModel` should NOT store a component as data. A model should store data and then renderer the data.

If you want to display a Rectangle, then add a custom `Icon` to the model. For an example of a custom icon see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700526/131872

Then in your `JTable` or `TableModel` you override the `getColumnClass(...)` method to return `Icon.class` for the second column and the table will use the default Icon renderer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5615516/131872

If you really need a custom renderer then you should extend from the default renderer since it will automatically provide support for highlighting and focus on rows and cells.

If you implement TableCellRenderer then you are responsible for highlighting and focus painting in the renderer based of the parameters passed to the method.